# Unneded number combination after replacing a number in a string

Tags: php, numbers, combinations

I get an unneeded number combination.

($_COOKIE):

> 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 901234567890123456789, 30

Should be ($_COOKIE):

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12... (till) 30

$_Get['id']="1"; (sorry, forgot to post it.)

Why that happens?

The code:

```
<?
ob_start(); 
$id=$_GET['id'];
if (!empty($id)){
    $id=str_replace('a9_','', $id);
    $value=$_COOKIE['NaudingasURL'];
    $exp = explode(", ", $value);
    if(in_array($id, $exp)){
        $value2=str_replace(', '.$id,"", ', '.$value);
        $value2=substr($value2, 2, strlen($value2));
        echo'r';
    }
    else{
        $value2=$value.', '.$id; echo'a';
    }
setcookie("NaudingasURL", $value2);
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

I'm calling it with *Jquery* ajax, but I don't thinks that's the problem.

Comment: please add example data for the $_GET and $_COOKIE arrays

Comment: Sorry Artefacto, but my English is not so good. What do you mean by saying "indent your code"? And btw sorry. I forgot to write the $_COOKIE and $_GET example. I was just furious at my code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are replacing every ",1" with and empty string. So 10 will be 0 and so on...

But i dont understand what exactly you want to achieve?

Ok, if it was what Max said, that you could do it like this:

```
$exp = explode(", ", $value);
if(in_array($id, $exp)){
    for ($i=0; $i<count($exp); $i++) {
      if ($exp[$i] == $id) {
         unset($exp[$i]);
      }
    }
    $value2 = implode(", ", $exp);
}
else{
    $value2 = implode(", ", $exp).', '.$id;
}
```

Comment: As far as I understood, he gets the cookie containing the list of ID's, removes from there the current ID, and saves the cookie back. Probably to indicate that the given ID is no longer needed for some future operation.

Comment: True, Max. So as i can see I replace every ", 1" and every ", 2" so my 10, 11, 12 and 21, 22, 23 turns to 012 and 123. Thanks for the answer! And what I want to achieve is http://www.naudingas.lt/?p=nustatymai

Comment: Ok, then i just added some code which should work.
May can still be optimized ;)

Comment: Yeah, for example you can do it like this (I was too late with my answer, as I'm not a PHP programmer :D ): http://pastebin.com/KtUfPfMq . First - you can use array_search. Second - you don't need to implode it back in 'else' part - you already have $value.